# GitX with Github, commit not showing up

Tags: github, gitx

I've created a few sample changes, staged the file, and committed. The commit is successful, but the changes do not show up on github, is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you push the changes? In Git (unlike SVN), committing only adds changes to your *local* repo; you still have to push the changes out to remote repos.

Comment: I guess I haven't, but how is that done using GitX? Does that have to be done via command line only?

Comment: @kylex: What version are you using?

Comment: @kylex: I don't think there's a way to do a push in the GitX GUI in that version.

Comment: If you're using one of the more up-to-date forks of gitx, they've got remote ops.  The original though does not.  in that case you'll have to fall back to good old `git push origin branchname`